# Using RestSharp to pass an object

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp

I am using C# and the RestSharp library to connect to a web service.

The remote server is requiring my to pass a single object, called obj, with two properties: login and pword.

So, the JSON object that gets passed to the web service should look like this:

```
obj={"login":"myusername","pword":"mypassword"}
```

However, I have not found an easy way to accomplish this.

If I use:

```
request.AddParameter("login","myusername");
request.AddParameter("pword","mypassword");
```

Then the two parameters are passed separately to the web service. I have also tried creating an object, called obj, with these two properties. Then using

```
request.AddObject(obj);
```

However this results in the same output to the web service call -- both elements are passed separately.

How can I get RestSharp to create a single object with these two properties?

EDIT:

I have figured out a way to make this work. There might be a better way to do this, but this does work.

First create an object containing the data:

```
var obj = new LoginRequest {login = login, pword = pword};
```

Then you can use the following:

```
request.AddParameter("obj",request.JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj));
```

This will result in a single JSON object, that contains the properties on the object passed into the Serialize method.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `request.AddBody(obj);`.